Lotus Notes 9.1 Backup and LotusScript
I’m working with IBM Notes 9.1 and need some assistance. My manager mentioned that they want to back up the existing information. One option they explored was manually downloading each incident along with its corresponding document. However, since the system has been running for years, this approach has become unfeasible due to the large amount of data.
Has anyone done something similar or have any information on this?
I’m exploring the possibility of creating a LotusScript to download the databases. I was informed that in the past someone performed a sort of backup in DB2 format, but there is no documentation available.

It all comes down to what you want to export?
If it is tabular/summary data, then you can export to CSV, XLS, SQL etc using some lotus script.  If you want rich text, attachments, or to render the documents to PDF or another image format then you will need to use 3rd party tools or java libraries.

Thank you very much, I also thought that I should work with Java. In fact, I need to download attachments. Another question, do you think there is a way to generalize the export process, given that there are several databases and different formats that have been used over the years? Sorry for the inconvenience, I have no experience with this kind of thing.
